# How to display a loading message or design while the page is loading in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, vb.net

How to display a loading message or image while the page is loading?

For example, when I click a button for adding items, it takes some time to finish loading, while it is loading, the page is active. What I want is a little loader to appear in the middle of the page and that page will turn inactive. When the page has finished loading, the loader will be gone and the page will get active.

Comment: What language / technology (apart from asp.net) are you using?

Comment: set a **div** with loading img or msg and `display:Block` on button click, and on serverside at the end of code set `display:none`.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - I am using vb, html and css

Comment: It may be worth checking [this answer from webarto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3535072/30512).

Comment: @Echilon- thanks for the suggestion but I want is to generate a loader using only asp.net, vb, html and ccs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ASP.NET Webforms

You can easily use an `UpdatePanel` associated with an `UpdateProgress` control.

UpdatePanel allow you to use async to interact with server. You can add an UpdateProgress control and link it with the UpdatePanel to show something (Gif, Text,..) when loading is in progress.

Find more informations [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETShowSpinnerImage-53ce1d10)

If you are using Asp.net MVC, you have to do the same trick using Ajax like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035329/update-panel-in-asp-net-mvc-3) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have tried
I had used YUI for this and added a panel to my code when the button is click

```
var ANIM_LOAD = YAHOO.namespace("anim_load");
ON button_onClick()
{
StartInitialLoadingPanel("Loading");
}
StartInitialLoadingPanel(msgStrng)
{
if (!TAB_COLLECTION.wait) {

        // Initialize the temporary Panel to display while waiting for external content to load
        TAB_COLLECTION.wait = new YAHOO.widget.Panel("wait",  
                                                                { width: "400px",
                                                                  x: window.screen.center,
                                                                  fixedcenter: true, 
                                                                  close: false, 
                                                                  draggable: false, 
                                                                  zindex:1000,
                                                                  modal: true,
                                                                  visible: true
                                                                } 
                                                              );

        TAB_COLLECTION.wait.setHeader(msgStr);

        TAB_COLLECTION.wait.setBody("<img src='../Images/loading_animation'>");

        TAB_COLLECTION.wait.render(document.body);
    }

    // Show the Panel
    TAB_COLLECTION.wait.show();
}
```

When the background is executed successfully you can call the method for stopping the animation as

```
function CancelInitialLoadPanel()
{
    //Hide the Panel    
    if (TAB_COLLECTION.wait) 
    {
        TAB_COLLECTION.wait.hide();
    }
}
```

Thanks for more details you can see [Here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Panel.html)

Comment: which code you will have to call the function on your button click and then call the panel function fom it.......
you can also have a look at http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/yuipanel/

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links of similar issues. Not sure how to manage the period it takes to render whole page but this might be a start.

[Hiding page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577413/hiding-page-loading)

[The page loading animation for hiding whole page load process ends long before It must fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577780/the-page-loading-animation-for-hiding-whole-page-load-process-ends-long-before-i)

Here is one using a timer control
[Display Ajax Loader while page rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242600/display-ajax-loader-while-page-rendering?rq=1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="loading"><img src="core/design/img/load/load.gif" /></div>');
});
$(window).load(function(){ 
    $('#loading').fadeOut(600, function(){
        $("#wrap").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#footer").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```